# query more than two columns with distinct in one column

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a table with four columns and want to display distinct output based on one columns only. How can I do this?

I tried using Max function on ID but it only works for two columns, anything more than two columns displays all records.

Any help is much appreciated

--EDIT--

Sample Data:

```
ID Name Date    Status
1  Sam  1/1/11    A
2  Sam  2/22/12   A
3  Jill 1/5/10    R
4  Jim  7/2/12    I
5  Jim  5/6/11    I
6  Bob  11/11/12  A
7  Bob  7/26/10   A
```

Output:

```
ID Name Date    Status
1  Sam  1/1/11    A
3  Jill 1/5/10    R
4  Jim  7/2/12    I
6  Bob  11/11/12  A
```

Comment: You can always do a group by on the one column but it will give you unpredictable results with the other columns

Comment: Please edit your question to show us some representative sample data and an example of what you would like to see as a result.

Comment: @GordThompson I just added sample data and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want values from the row with the lowest `ID` value for each `Name`.  Use a `GROUP BY` subquery to get the minimum `ID` per `Name`.  Then `INNER JOIN` your table to the subquery.

```
SELECT y2.ID, y2.Name, y2.Date, y2.Status
FROM
    YourTable AS y2
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT y.Name, Min(y.ID) AS MinOfID
            FROM YourTable AS y
            GROUP BY y.Name
        ) AS sub
    ON y2.ID = sub.MinOfID
```

Comment: @GordThompson What if I want Distinct "ID" and "Name" values. If the combination of ID and Name makes it a distinct record then display else not.

Comment: @user793468 The combination of [ID] and [Name] (or [ID] and *anything*) will always be distinct for every row because the [ID] values are distinct for every row.

Comment: @GordThompson Sorry, my mistake. I meant Name and any additional column. Lets say Name and Date

Comment: In that case, change the subquery to `GROUP BY` Name and Date. `SELECT y.Name, y.Date, Min(y.ID) AS MinOfID FROM YourTable AS y GROUP BY y.Name, y.Date`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to return from your other columns, but something like this would return the unique values in col1, and the minimum values from the other columns.

```
SELECT 
    Col1,
    MIN(Col2) AS Col2,
    MIN(Col3) AS Col3,
    MIN(Col4) AS Col4
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but try:

SELECT DISTINCT columnYouFilterBy, column2, column3, column4 FROM yourTable